# Probability to cover an interval with a collection of randomly centered intervals

Tags: probability, interval-arithmetic

My problem is the following. In the middle of an interval $L$ of length $l$ is placed an interval of length $k$ (meaning the interval stretches from $[\frac{l}{2}-\frac{k}{2}, \frac{l}{2}+\frac{k}{2}]$ ).
Then we randomly create $n$ intervals, $I_1$,$I_2$, ..., $I_n$ of length $m < k$ whose centers are distributed uniformly and independently on the interval $L$.

What I would like to compute is $P$($[\frac{l}{2}-\frac{k}{2}, \frac{l}{2}+\frac{k}{2}]$ $\subseteq$ $\bigcup_{i=1}^n I_i$)

I have no idea how to express the union of the $I_i$s so that I can get to the answer if it exists (it's not coming from an exercise so I don't know if there's an analytical solution to that question actually). Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: The first step I'd make is to fix attention on the case $l = 2$ (because all other cases are scaled versions of this), center the interval at the origin, and replace $k$ with $h = k/2$, the *radius* of the intervals. Then you are trying to cover $[-(1-h), 1-h]$ with $n$ intervals of radius $< h$, whose centers are uniformly randomly distributed on $[-1, 1]$. One question: is $m$ random as well, i.e., is each of the little intervals some random length that's less than $k$? Or do you have a fixed $m < k$, and use a bunch of intervals all of length $m$?

Comment: Also...if you imagine "splatting" the small intervals onto the larger one, the "target" area will gradually get more and more covered ... and the chances of covering any "missing bits" with the next "splat" goes steadily down. In this sense, this reminds me of the coupon-collector's problem. I'm not sure that's of any value, but it might give you a starting point.

Comment: Hello, $m$ is fixed in my problem and $n$ is fixed too.

Comment: Well...if $mn < k$, the the probability is zero. :) Aside from that, I see no obvious way to frame things to gain any insight -- sorry. It seems like a nice problem.

Comment: Hello, it would be nice if it was the case but actually $mn$=$5*k$.

Comment: What happen if the center of a random interval is $<-l/2+m/2$ ($I_j$ is not fully contained in $L$). Is the center uniformly distributed in $[(-l+m)/2, (l-m)/2]$ ? (I'm talking about when $L$ is centered around $0$)

Comment: Hello, the center is supposed to be a point of impact so the center cannot be outside $L$ but the interval can extend outside $L$ though.